# Is there anyway to end a delegate if I no longer care about the result?

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I have a piece of code that searches several third party APIs.  I have the searches split into 2 groups based on the search criteria.  I start both searches because each search is quite timely, but if the first group of searches results in an match I don't want to wait around for the second search group to finish.  So basically what I have is:

```
Dictionary<string, string> result = null;
NameSearchDelegate nameDel = new NameSearchDelegate(SearchByName);
IAsyncResult nameTag = nameDel.BeginInvoke(name, null, null);
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(telNum))
{
    result = SearchByTelNum(telNum);//Will return null if a match is not found
}
if(null == result)
{
    result = nameDel.EndInvoke(nameTag);
}
//End the delegate to prevent memory leak
//else
//{
//    nameDel.EndInvoke(nameTag)
//}
return result;
```

So I want to start the SearchByName before I call SearchByTelNum in case it does not find a match, however if it does find a match I don't want to have to wait for SearchByName to finish before returning the match.  Is there any way to simply end or cancel that delegate if I no longer need its result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I cancel methods through delegates in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410211/can-i-cancel-methods-through-delegates-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Just think like a manager - don't _tell_ the delegate that it's work is no longer useful, let it go on and ignore its results.

Comment: Yes, I agree with D Stanley. You can invoke two search and just use the first returned results. Killing the delegate may have no help for saving resources in this criteria.

Comment: But by not calling EndInvoke on the delegate don't I allow a possible memory leak? [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/b18b0a27-e2fd-445a-bcb3-22a315cd6f0d/)

And for reference, it is .NET 4.0

Comment: I think that I found the answer that I was looking for in the thread referenced by John Koerner found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1410344/1757384.  By using a BackgroundWorker, (System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker) I can call the CancelAsync method to "cancel" the thread.  I'm trying it out now and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @JohnLoomis: If `BackgroundWorker` does the trick for you, write it up as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker. I wasn't necessarily using it in the way it is intended to be used but it was able to do what I needed.  So basically what my new code looks like is:

```
Dictionary<string, string> telResult = null,
                           nameResult = null;

BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
bw.DoWork += (obj, e) => nameResult = SearchByName(name, bw);
bw.RunWorkerAsync();

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(telNum))
    telResult = SearchByTelNum(telNum);//Will return null if a match is not found

if(telResult != null)
{
    bw.CancelAsync;
    return telResult;
}

bool hasTimedOut = false;
int i = timeOutCount;
while (bw.IsBusy && !hasTimedOut)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    if (0 == --i) hasTimedOut = true;
}

return nameResult;
```

And to make sure there are no bugs, I had to make sure that SearchByName periodically checks if bw.CancellationPending equals true, and ends the method in that case.  CancelAsync does not end the worker thread, it simply alerts the worker thread that caller thread has canceled it.

Also I could have simply used

```
while(bw.IsBusy) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
```

to wait for the method to complete, but if something bad happens in SearchByName you could end up waiting forever in an infinite loop.  This way I can set an amount of time before the method is considered to have timed out and the caller thread just goes on with life. In this case, since I check bw.IsBusy every .5 seconds, the timeout length is equal to timeOutCount / 2 seconds.

Ok I think I have thoroughly answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I have handled this by defining an abortable parameter object

```
public class AbortableParameter<T>
{
    public T Parameter { get; private set }
    public bool ShouldAbort { get; set; }
    public AbortableParameter(T parameter)
    {
        Parameter = parameter;
        ShouldAbort = false;
    }
}
```

Just create an instance of this class with any parameters you want to pass to the delegate and keep a reference to it; setting it to true if the delegate should exit.  The delegate then needs to periodically check `ShouldAbort` and exit gracefully when it becomes `true`.

This is the downside, the delegate must check periodically or it won't matter if it should abort or not.

It is also possible to have the `ShouldAbort` property's set method kill the delegate when it is set to true, but this is not a graceful exit and should be avoided in most cases -- but it does have the benefit of not requiring the delegate polling.